# customized bootstrap btn not working on chrome

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I had to customize button in bootstrap for my webpage. It works well on IE but not on Chrome. Where did I go wrong. Below is my html.

```css
       .btn-secondary {
        background-color: #283238;
        color: #05a9d0;
        border-color: #05a9d0;
        border-radius: 0;
        font-family:Helvetica Neue;
        font-size:20px;
        width:auto;
        opacity:0.9;
        border:1px solid;
        height:auto;
  
    }
    .btn-secondary:hover,
    .btn-secondary:focus,
    .btn-secondary:active    {
        background-color: #283238;
        color: #ffffff;
        border-color: #05a9d0;
    }
```

```html
<div id="banner" class=" text-center vertical-center">
    <div class="slide-top" id="valign-IE" data-plugin-options='{"speed":1500}'>
    <img src="img/logo_page.svg" class="banner-logo"/><br />

    <button  class="btn btn-primaryLogin" onclick="document.location.href='signin.aspx'">Login</button>
    <button type="button" class ="btn btn-secondary" >REQUEST ACCESS FOR SIGNUP</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: could you explain what are you trying to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/bd3ce0dg/

Answer (score 0):

window.location is read/write on all compliant browsers.

document.location is read-only in Internet Explorer but read/write in Gecko-based browsers (Firefox, SeaMonkey).

use window.location instead of document.location